# how to use assert and == in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, assert

I'm trying to learn python. I found a question saying correct this:

```
def main():
    assert ___ == type("Hello World").__name__
    assert ___ == isinstance("Hello World", str)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I tried:

```
__some__={}
def main():
    assert __some__ == type("Hello World").__name__
    assert __some__ == isinstance("Hello World", str)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this, I'm getting `AssertionError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 6, in <module>
    main()
  Line 3, in main
    assert __some__ == type("Hello World").__name__
AssertionError
```

I found that `assert` is used to specify a condition and an exception will be raised when that condition fails. I even used python tutor, but if I put `assert somevariable` I'm getting assertion error. I'm unable to understand to understand how to use `==` and assert to accomplish some task.

Comment: Executing that code yields a `NameError: name '__' is not defined`. That's not an assertion failure.  You need to assert a well-defined expression.

Comment: @user3553031 i declared a variable and kept at that place i'm getting assertion error

Comment: In that case, please show us the exact code that's failing and the exact error that you're getting.

Comment: @user3553031 codepad link http://codepad.org/RBYJPssJ

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code and the traceback from the exception it is raising. In the future, please include those in your questions from the beginning!

Comment: @saimadan you understand that your task is to find the right thing to replace `___`? Have you tried running the expressions to see what values they give?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i understood that i'm supposed to replace something to make it work but actually i did not understand the question and what the statements are doing

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for the edit next time i will make sure that i will follow all of your suggestions

Comment: @saimadan then why not try running e.g. `print(isinstance("Hello World", str))` to see what you get? Or read the [docs for `isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)? Or read up on [assertions in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot i will use print function and the associated documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you posted on codepad.org is

```
__some__={}
def main():
    assert __some__ == type("Hello World").__name__
    assert __some__ == isinstance("Hello World", str)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

`type("Hello World").__name__` is `'str'` and `__some__` is `{}`, so of course they don't match.  Likewise, `isinstance("Hello World", str)` is `True`, so it doesn't match either.  Your conditions are false, so the assertions fail and throw AssertionError.  If on the other hand, you tried `assert 'str' == type("Hello World").__name__`, you'd get no exception because that comparison is true.

Also, you shouldn't declare your own variables using names like `__foo__`.  By convention, those are reserved for special variables created by Python.

Comment: thanks a lot can you suggest some sources to learn python 2.7 other than documentation

Comment: can you please explain a bit what that statements are doing actually i did not understand the type("hello world").__name__ .what is .__name__ and what is it doing

Comment: `"Hello World"` is a string.  `type()` is a built-in function that returns an object containing information about the type of an object, so `type("Hello World")` returns an object describing strings.  That object has a field named `__name__`, which the string `str`, indicating that the name of the type of `"Hello World"` is `"str"`.  Try executing any of those statements in the Python interpreter and see what it tells you.

Comment: i understood now from now on i will use the command line to understand  any statements thanks a lot

Comment: assert False == 'c' in 'apple'      i'm getting assertion error for this can you help i think this is sort of precedence issue

Comment: Yes, it is a precedence issue.  The `==` is evaluated first; `False == 'c'` is false, so then you check `False in 'apple'`, which is also false.  How do you think that you should override precedence?  Hint: it's the same way that you would override precedence in an ordinary arithmetic expression.

Comment: Imagine that you want to add 2 to 3, then multiply the result by 4. Writing `2 + 3 * 4` would be incorrect, because order of operations specifies that multiplication be applied first.  How would you re-write that to get the correct result?

Comment: (2 + 3)*4 i would do this

Comment: Right.  So it's `assert False == ('c' in 'apple')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51223/discussion-between-saimadan-and-user3553031)